# Can't access hard disk partitions when Dual booting Windows 10 with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I am dual booting my Dell XPS 13 which came with Windows 10, with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I reach installation, and the screen asks where to install, I only get my live drive (USB with Ubuntu) as an option. It is as if my laptop's storage does not exist. 
I tried to see if I could access my laptop's drives and partitions through GParted and the terminal, but neither could access them.
I have turned off Secureboot, hibernate, and fast startup in power options.

Please help!

Comment: First of all ignore the (partially) wrong answer below. Go to UEFI settings and make sure the SATA mode is AHCI (you may need to install AHCI support in Windows before changing this mode). Then disable legacy/CSM to assure you're booting in UEFI mode.

Comment: I tried enabling AHCI as the SATA mode, but in that case Windows wouldn't boot. I don't want to lose Windows, is there a workaround to this?

Comment: You could try a newer Ubuntu; that might add the drivers for non-AHCI access on your system. You could also ask on a Windows forum about how to switch to using Windows with AHCI mode enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions at this link helped me solve my problem.

https://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/